# How to create a table in Oracle/SQL, with one of its column is calculated by columns in other tables

Tags: oracle11g

I want to create a table called ORDERS with columns as ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID references customers(CUSTOMER_ID),ITEM_CODE references items(ITEM_CODE), QUANTITY and AMOUNT. 
I have a table called ITEMS with columns ITEM_CODE, ITEM_NAME and PRICE.
In the ORDERS table, I want the column AMOUNT to be filled automatically by multiplying PRICE in Item table and QUANTITY in ORDERS table. 
I tried

```
create table orders
(
Order_ID number not null primary key,
Customer_ID references customers(Customer_ID),
Item_Code references items(Item_Code),
Quantity  number as (select (i.price*o.Quantity) from items i, orders o where i.Item_code=o.item_code)
);
```

But it is not working as it is expecting some expressions. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You have to use trigger instead of query as default value

Comment: Thank You. Can you explain it if you dont mind please